# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stacktrace-js' in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3, stacktrace.js

When I am trying to get the stacktrace via `stacktrace-js`, I get this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stacktrace-js' in ionic3

Please help me.

**My Ionic Info:**

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.7
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.19.1
```

**Global packages:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

**Local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

**System:**

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

**Environment Variables:**

```
ANDROID_HOME     : E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
```